# Scrollview не работает

Tags: android, прокрутка

привет всем.
не вмещаются компоненты на активити.
поэтому решил использовать скроллвью.
но проблема в том, что приложение вылетает с ошибкой, когда я хочу открыть активити с моим скролом.
"unfortunately has stopped"
в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Дежурный экстрасенс пока спит, придётся подробнее описать проблему. Попробуйте вытащить стектрейс эксепшна, который вываливается при открытии scrollview и запостить сюда.

Comment: добавил код.

Comment: я же написал тебе ответ =) и что бы добавить бэкграунд не надо вводить еще 1 вью, поставить тег в RelativeLayout

Comment: спасибо.
но как теперь быть?
все запихать в LinearLayout?

Comment: да, можно так

Comment: ой, спасибки!

Answer (score 2):

экстрасенс проснулся и думает, что ты пытаешься вложить в ScrollView больше чем 1 дочерний элемент